# How to match a file name suffix

Tags: shell-script, filenames

How to verify if the name of a `.xml` file name ended with `.any-string`? e.g.      .previous or .backup or bck12    etc ...

I need to print the XML file name except for XML files that end with `.any-string` or have anything after the `.xml`

How to verify this with grep or awk or sed or perl or any other idea? Something like

```
 file=machine_configuration.xml
 file=machine_configuration.xml.previos
 file=machine_configuration.xml.backup
 echo $file | .....
```

Examples:

1. `machine_configuration.xml`: yes
2. `machine_configuration.xml.OLD`: no
3. `machine_configuration.xml-HOLD: no
4. `machine_configuration.xml10`: no
5. `machine_configuration.xml@hold`: no
6. `machine_configuration.xml_need_to_verifi_this`: no

Comment: this isnt typical xml file -:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the regex end-anchor (`$`), e.g.:

```
echo "$file" | grep '\.xml$'
```

To find all files ending with "xml", I would suggest using the `find` command, e.g.:

```
find . -name '*.xml'
```

Would recursively list all xml files from current directory.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to detect whether a file name ends in `.xml`.

```
case $file in
  *.xml) echo "$file";;
esac
```

If you want to do something when the file name doesn't match:

```
case $file in
  *.xml) echo "matched $file";;
  *) echo "skipping $file";;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the filename in a variable already, a good approach would be [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

```
$ echo $file
text.xmllsls
$ echo ${file%.xml*}.xml
text.xml
```

Where the `%.xml*` is that the last occurrence of `.xml` and everything behind it will be deleted. Therefor I also echoed a .xml again.

Or, to have the test as well

```
$ file=test.xmlslsls
$ file2=${file%.xml*}.xml
$ if [ $file = $file2 ]; then echo $file; fi
$
$
$ file="test.xml"
$ file2=${file%.xml*}.xml
$ if [ $file = $file2 ]; then echo $file; fi
test.xml
```

Or, on a single line

```
$ if [ $file = ${file%.xml*}.xml ]; then echo $file; fi
```

Answer (score -1):

easiest way ...

```
echo  file=machine_configuration.xml | cut -d '.' -f 1
```